# can Ext JS do snap-to-grid for drag/drop/resize UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, extjs

Currently planning for a time-line application. Each elements on the time line will need to be resizable and draggable with a snap-to-grid positioning similar to jQuery UI's

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#snap-to-grid (the snap to 20x20 kinda thing)

Is this feature available with Ext JS? Been googling around without any results. Can anyone point me to some examples please?

Answer (score 2):

You may get some inspiration from http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/custom-views.html

**Edit**
[Source code on Github](https://github.com/bmoeskau/Extensible/downloads)

Comment: Thanks Pumbaa. I've never heard of Github before, going to have to browse around :)Ensible kind of does what I want. Too bad it doesn't look as good as jquery's :(